# AWS CDK Dynamodb table construct creates table but attribute 'role_arn' is undefined

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I have created Dynamodb table using the below construct by giving the name of existing table:

```
self.dynamodb_table = aws_dynamodb.Table(
                self, id,
                partition_key=aws_dynamodb.Attribute(name=table_pk, type=aws_dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING),
                sort_key=aws_dynamodb.Attribute(name=table_sk, type=aws_dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING),
                time_to_live_attribute=table_ttl_attr,
                table_name=table_name,
                billing_mode=billing_mode,
                stream=stream
            )
```

Expecting that object `self.dynamodb_table` gets populated with the new table. But when I try to access the attribute `table_arn` using `self.dynamodb_table.table_arn`, it complains saying attribute is not defined.

Do someone know of the way to access the ARN for this table.

Answer (score 0):

I used boto in order to get table instance. That is the way I am able to also get ARN for this table. Seems like documentation for Python CDK is flawed.

```
import boto3

dynamodb_boto_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
tableoutput = dynamodb_boto_client.describe_table(TableName='ABCD')
        table_arn = tableoutput["Table"]["TableArn"]
```